# Concatenate values from columns with the same name and always changing locations

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is how [image: my data] looks like.

I need to extract

[image: concatenated values like this].

However, the location of these columns is always changing depending on a new data refresh. So, this round it is columns B, C, D, but next time it could be F, G, H. But they are always consecutive. The column names stay the same, which is the same for all columns.

*The solution has to be applicable for each cell and do not have a spill. Because I will be extracting them one by one in different locations.*

I have used concatenate and Hlookup formulas.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```vb
=LET(dataRaw,A1:G4,
header, TAKE(dataRaw,1),
data,FILTER(DROP(dataRaw,1),header="Custom field (Continents)"),
BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r, TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, r))))
```

It filters the raw data to return "Custom field (Continents)" columns only.

And then applies `TEXTJOIN` by row.

[image]

++++++++++++++++
Edit according to comment:

```vb
=LET(row,A2:G2,
header, A1:G1,
data,FILTER(row,header="Custom field (Continents)"),
BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r, TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, r))))
```

Adjust `row` to the row for which you need the result.

Comment: The solution has to work for each cell and not spill because I will extracting Rows 8, 9, 10 in different locations, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Solution per OP's edit:

> *The solution has to be applicable for each cell and do not have a*
> *spill. Because I will be extracting them one by one in different*
> *locations.*

---

Since OP mentions that they do not have a `SPILL` can assume that they may or may not have access to any `LAMBDA()` helper function that said, the solution can be achieved using `IF()` with `TEXTJOIN()` or using `FILTER()` (if applicable to OP's version) with `TEXTJOIN()`

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B7</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(2:2,$1:$1="Custom Field (Continents)",""))
```

---

Or, Using `TEXTJOIN()` with `IF()`

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(($1:$1="Custom Field (Continents)")*(2:2<>""),2:2,""))
```

---

Or, Using `REPT()`

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,REPT(2:2,$1:$1="Custom Field (Continents)"))
```

---

**Notes:** `TEXTJOIN()` function is available from `Excel 2019+` onwards as per `MSFT` [Documentations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c). Also in `Excel 2019` users would need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

---

Or, the one which supports `Excel 2016+` onwards:

[image]

---

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(IF(($1:$1="Custom Field (Continents)")*(2:2<>""),", "&2:2,"")),", ",,1)
```

---

**Addendum:** All above formulas needs to be filled down, and as well as based on one's `Excel Versions` may need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

---